# "with open as f" won't open and It doesn't even say there's a problem

Tags: python

```
import requests
res = requests.get("https://google.com")
res.raise_for_status()

print(len(res.text))
print(res.text)

with open('mygoogle.html',"w",encoding=('utf-8')) as f :
    f.write(res.text)
```

The `with open as f` part doesn't work.
If it does, it has to open new file, but it doesn't.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? You are using a relative path, so it may simply be creating the file somewhere other than where you expect it.

Comment: Hi nomaclod, welcome to the site. I've edited your post to get the code to format properly, please feel free to [edit] yourself if I've made any mistakes.

Comment: the code is working fine. you are creating the file at some other location. Check what is your current working directory by doing `import os` `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Thank you. As Chepner said, the route was in a different location

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this code and it works properly - `mygoogle.html` gets written and contains the expected content. The issue is likely outside of the script then. Since it is using a relative path, the issue could be that the file is getting written somewhere where you don't expect it due to the working directory not being set how you expect - Windows often defaults to `C:\Windows\system32` or your user profile directory (`%userprofile%` aka `C:\users\<username>`) for new cmd instances.